# How the j_security_check validates the user ? I want to remove the default and keep it for ldap authenication

Tags: authentication, j-security-check

I am using j_security_check in my web application using jetty. The below is the form in my `jsp` file.

```
<form action="/j_security_check" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>Username:<input type="text" name="j_username"/></tr>
    <tr>Password:<input type="password" name="j_password"/></tr>
        <tr><input type="submit" value="Login"/></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Actually I am trying to authenticate the user from the LDAP server. But for the first time, when I try to authenticate, it is logging in directly. After that when i try to access with those credentials, it is logging in directly.

I am not sure about where the `j_security_check` keeps the username and password, each time when it tries to authenticate or validate. Any ideas in this regard.

The below is the `web.xml` code i kept it for form based authentication for the reference.

FORM

```
    <!-- Note, this needs to match whats in the AdminWebAppLauncher -->
    <realm-name>myRealm</realm-name>

    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/loginError.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Any idea on this. Please suggest..!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two tables in your database. The first one contains `username` and `password` and the second one contains `username` and `role`.
The alternative is to create one table which contains `username`, `password` and, `role`.

Also you should add the following xml tags into your `server.xml` or `context.xml`:

```
<Realm  className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
        driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"
        connectionName="root" connectionPassword="password"
        userTable="user" userNameCol="user_name" userCredCol="user_pass"
        userRoleTable="user_role_link" roleNameCol="role_id" />
```